# How to prove Gauss summation of integers with proof assistants using forward reasoning?

Tags: isabelle, forward-proof, backward-proof

As shown in an [exercise here](http://typessummerschool07.cs.unibo.it/courses/wenzel-isar-exercises.pdf), we can prove the [Gauss summation](https://letstalkscience.ca/educational-resources/backgrounders/gauss-summation) (that $\Sigma_{i=0..n}{i} = n \cdot (n + 1)/2$ ) in Isabelle/Isar using mathematical induction, as follows.

```
theorem
  fixes n::nat
  shows"2 * (∑i=0..n. i) = n * (n + 1)" 
  by (induct n) simp_all
```

The proof is a one-liner with much details hidden or handled automatically.

However, this seems to be very different from the intuitive proof by Gauss that basically adds the sequence of numbers $1...n$, and a reversed copy of itself. The above Isabelle proof is a backward one, which is perfectly fine and is a textbook example of mathematical induction. But it still differs from the ideas of Gauss's famous proof, which seems to be a forward construction and then verification that it's what is wanted.

I am just wondering:

*Is there a way to do a forward style proof that faithfully replicates Gauss's proof in Isabelle or similar proof assistants?*

(This example almost changed my perception of which proof style is simpler.)

Comment: To use Gauss' method, you need *three* inductions: One to prove that you can reverse a summation, one to prove that two summations can be added term by term, one to prove that a summation with constant terms is a multiplication.

Answer (score 10):

Like @Bubbler, I think a nice forward proof can be done using a chain of equalities, to spell out each step:

```
theorem
  fixes n::nat
  shows"2 * (∑i=1..n. i) = n * (n + 1)" 
proof-
  have "2 * (∑i=1..n. i) = (∑i=1..n. i) + (∑i=1..n. i)" by simp
  also have "… = (∑i=1..n. i) + (∑i=1..n. (n + 1 - i))"
    by (subst sum.atLeastAtMost_rev) simp
  also have "… = (∑i=1..n. (i + (n + 1 - i)))"
    using sum.distrib[symmetric].
  also have "… = (∑i=1..n. n + 1)" by simp
  also have "… = n * (n + 1)" by simp
  finally show ?thesis.
qed
```

I took the liberty to start the summation at `1`, not at `0`, because I presumptuously expect that that’s how Gauss thought about this list of numbers.

Comment: I haven’t touched Isabelle in a while, so if something I am doing here is (no longer) idiomatic Isabelle, feel free to refine

Comment: This porting phenomenon also occurs on codegolf stackexchange. We might want to look at the policies there?

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn’t have thought of repeating his answer in Isabelle if the original question wasn’t explicitly talking about Isabelle and tagged [isabelle]; this wasn’t just porting for porting’s sake, but merely trying to give an answer that the OP might find more useful.

Comment: Yeah, so I agree that it's not applicable in this particular case. But for the general case I think it's worth asking on meta.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly sure if Lean counts as "similar proof assistant" to Isabelle, but Lean mathlib [has the proof of essentially the same statement](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/bb1b56c76712c8aa9239c686c88ab5052e296dac/src/algebra/big_operators/intervals.lean#L152), using [calc mode](https://leanprover-community.github.io/extras/calc.html) which allows to gradually transform the left side of an equality to the right side. (here `range n` is a range from 0 to `n-1` inclusive)

```
lemma sum_range_id_mul_two (n : ℕ) :
  (∑ i in range n, i) * 2 = n * (n - 1) :=
calc (∑ i in range n, i) * 2 = (∑ i in range n, i) + (∑ i in range n, (n - 1 - i)) :
  by rw [sum_range_reflect (λ i, i) n, mul_two]
... = ∑ i in range n, (i + (n - 1 - i)) : sum_add_distrib.symm
... = ∑ i in range n, (n - 1) : sum_congr rfl $ λ i hi, add_tsub_cancel_of_le $
  nat.le_pred_of_lt $ mem_range.1 hi
... = n * (n - 1) : by rw [sum_const, card_range, nat.nsmul_eq_mul]
```

It does not use induction on the surface, but it does use many lemmas which are individually proved with induction under the hood. Also, simplifying `(i + (n - 1 - i))` to `(n - 1)` is rather complicated because, due to the nature of `-` on `nat`, one needs to assert that `i` is at most `n - 1` inside the summation. The other three steps correspond to Gauss's three-step proof (twice sum is sum with itself reversed; two sums are zipped so that it becomes a sum of constant; a sum of constant is the constant times length of the sum).